# Persisting memcached (1.4.14) across reboots

Tags: memcached

I recently installed `memcached` via the commands `sudo apt-get install memcached` and `sudo apt-get install python-memcache`.

I next did some quick settings in `/etc/memcached.conf` (attached at the end of the question). For the record, I'm connecting via unix socket. Next I tried `sudo service memcached restart` to get it up and running.

However, it didn't work. I then manually created a dir in `/var/run` called `memcached` and ran `chown memcache:root /var/run/memcached`.

Then doing `sudo service memcached restart` was a success.

However, if I do `sudo reboot` and log back into the machine after the reboot,the sock file (and the folder with it) are gone.

How do I get memcached to persist in this scenario? I'm on Ubuntu 14.04, and the memcached config file is as follows:

---

```
# memcached default config file
# 2003 - Jay Bonci <jaybonci@debian.org>
# This configuration file is read by the start-memcached script provided as
# part of the Debian GNU/Linux distribution.

# Run memcached as a daemon. This command is implied, and is not needed for the
# daemon to run. See the README.Debian that comes with this package for more
# information.
-d

# Log memcached's output to /var/log/memcached
logfile /var/log/memcached.log

# Be verbose
-v

# Be even more verbose (print client commands as well)
# -vv

# Start with a cap of 64 megs of memory. It's reasonable, and the daemon default
# Note that the daemon will grow to this size, but does not start out holding this much
# memory
#-m 64
-m 320

# Default connection port is 11211
#-p 11211

# Run the daemon as root. The start-memcached will default to running as root if no
# -u command is present in this config file
-u memcache

# Specify which IP address to listen on. The default is to listen on all IP addresses
# This parameter is one of the only security measures that memcached has, so make sure
# it's listening on a firewalled interface.
#-l 127.0.0.1
-s /var/run/memcached/memcached.sock
-a 0777

# Limit the number of simultaneous incoming connections. The daemon default is 1024
# -c 1024

# Lock down all paged memory. Consult with the README and homepage before you do this
# -k

# Return error when memory is exhausted (rather than removing items)
# -M

# Maximize core file limit
# -r
```

---

Please ask for more information in case you need it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem by delving into memcached's init.d startup script.

I added the following lines at the head of the script (they weren't there already):

```
if [ ! -d /var/run/memcached ]; then

        mkdir /var/run/memcached

        chown memcache /var/run/memcached

fi
```

I saved, and then set it to start automatically on boot with:

```
sudo update-rc.d memcached defaults
sudo update-rc.d memcached enable
```